# Is there a way to extract only values of a certain type of an interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have been trying to get the following to work with conditional and mapped types to no avail. I might be missing something obvious, but suppose I had the interface:

```
interface TestInterface {
    x: 1,
    y: "hello"
}
```

Is there a way to get just this:

```
interface TestInterfaceButJustStrings {
    y: "hello"
}
```

Like this:

```
type ExtractValues<T, U> = /* ??? */;
type TestInterfaceButJustStrings = ExtractValues<TestInterface, string>;
```

Where `ExtractValues<T, U>` is type `T` with only properties whose values match the type `U`?

Comment: Related, might be of interest: [Omitting all properties in an object which are `undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62601403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay! Thanks to @VLAZ I was able to figure it out. Solution:

```
type MatchingValues<T, U> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never
}[keyof T];

type ExtractValues<T, U> = Pick<T, MatchingValues<T, U>>;
```

First, `MatchingValues` creates a union of all keys that extend type `U`.

Then, the `Pick` creates a new type that only has the properties of `T` that are also in `MatchingValues`. So, we end up with a type that only has properties that match our `U` type.